# How can vertical align bottom and top at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I want to vertical align some elements at the top of the td element and some other elements to be at the bottom of td element .

this is my code :

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="position:relative;vertical-align:top;">
                <a runat="server" href='#' class="Up">
                </a>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="ProductNameLabel" CssClass="Up"/>
                <br /> 
                <asp:Label ID="SummaryLabel" CssClass="Up"/>

                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" CssClass="Down" />
                <br />
                <a runat="server" href="#" class="Down">                        
                </a>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="Down" />
            </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

The elements from the "Up" class i want to be displayed at the top of the td and the elements in the "Down" class at the bottom of the td .

i tried this css :

```
.Up {
    top:0px;   
}

.Down {
    bottom:0px;    
}
```

And it didn't work . Can someone help me find the solution ?

Comment: Try to add position: relative to your class.

Comment: `vertical-align: top;` and `vertical-align: bottom;` ? [w3c has more info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

Comment: i tried both , what Dev'Hamz and jamez14 suggested. it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you only provided HTML and CSS in your example.

In any case, I think what you are looking for is position:absolute

```
.Up {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;   
}

.Down {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;    
}
```

This will position them relative to the first parent that has a position:relative on it.

Note, I also removed the px from your 0 as it's not necessary to specify that when the value is 0. 0em = 0px = 0% = 0

Here is [a more complete example](http://jsfiddle.net/QmxhS/).

Comment: Can you provide the example without all the ASP cluttering it? That just confuses matters.

Comment: let's say i have something like this

Comment: <td>
<img class="up"></img>
<img class="down"></img>
</td> and i need the 1st image to be up and the second at the bottom

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example in jsfiddle showing how position:absolute works for this. It does depend somewhat on how much control you have over the elements in your table cell. If you have more than 1 element set at bottom:0, then they will overlap each other and hide them. So you'll need to set a left: on that as well to make them sit side by side.